# Rails application without routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to RoR and I have an API rails application that does not have `routes.rb` file.
I know it works but I don't know how.

What are the possible approaches(exept `routes.rb` file) to route requests?

Comment: Not having a `routes.rb` and defining the routes somewhere else seemed like a really bad practice for me.

Rails has a complex Class loading order and overwriting the default framework conventions may lead unexpected behavior in your application.

Answer (score 1):

In rails it's not necessary to have a `routes.rb` file. Any file/files inside `config` directory might have route destination like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # Your routes here ..
end
```